# UIViewController does not get disposed

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, xamarin, lifecycle

I am noticing intermittent crashes on my large app written in Xamarin iOS 7.2.2. Instruments shows me that my app is grows in memory usage without really going down.

I have made sure to nullify all events in my UIViewControllers, and despite that, my UIViewControllers are not being disposed.

I know they are not being disposed because breakpoints on them never execute.

Exemplary Dispose method:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        _someViewController = null;
        _otherView = null;
        ReleaseDesignerOutlets();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

I am not doing anything fancy in them, except nullifying references to other views and releasing designer outlets, yet it never gets called.

Why is Dispose not being called after my view controller is popped from the navigation controller?

Comment: I'm also having a similar problem after the upgrade

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following pattern helped minimize memory leaks

1. Do not keep UIViewController's & UIView's in memory, always create them as needed and explicitly dispose when not needed.
2. Within a dispose method, dispose "owned" UIViewController & UIView's
3. Within dispose method, manually remove from parent and dispose all subviews
4. Within dispose method, nullify all references to controllers & views
5. Within dispose method, nullify all events
6. Use new Refcount feature and new GC (project options)
7. If using Sqlite, do this on startup

```
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.SetConfig(Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLiteConfig.Serialized);
```

Even though these steps should not be necessary according to Xamarin & iOS documentation, without them my app would never release memory. Now it collects reasonably, which shows that Xamarin GC between complex object graphs spanning ObjC & mono runtime are not properly collected (likely due to cyclic references). Manually breaking the object references simplifies the object reference graph allowing GC to occur much quicker and more reliably than otherwise.

Xamarin should really look into this, intermittent crashes & memory leaks occur for complex apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely something still holding a reference to your view controller.

In some case it can be hard to identify what's holding the reference. Since you're using a version more recent than [7.2.1](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_7/xamarin.ios_7.2/#1) you should try the **New Refcount** extension to the GC (either Bohem or sgen).

There is more information (and links) from the [release notes](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_7/xamarin.ios_7.2/#1) but, in a nutshell, this extension will better track the native object lifetime and it also remove most backing fields (that could hold such references).

Comment: Refcount did not make any difference.

Comment: Then the reference is likely kept by your own code (not a backing field or being delayed by something else). You can use **HeapShot** to find what's holding this reference and/or file a bug report @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com In that case please attach your code or a subset (that duplicates it) along with instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, did not know about Heapshot despite googling this issue for quite some time. Unfortunately, app crashes too intermittently with monotouch_release_managed_ref for reliable testing. These crashes seem to happen when connected to debugger. Using Instruments, I managed to confirm memory releases but I had to manually dispose views as much as possible everywhere and manually nullify event handlers and nullify references whereever possible. Seems to have worked somewhat. I maximally exploit c# closures, anon methods/types which likely leads to complex object reference graphs.